# Form validation of submit button

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

So, I'm trying to disable the submit button until the gift voucher is selected. How do I go by this? here is a code snippet for some context. I'm using php Symfony 2.8. So, this is a .twig file in my project.

```
<div class="grid_7 alpha omega data-field" style="width:260px;">
        <div class="grid_3 alpha omega">Amount</div>
                                <div class="grid_4 alpha omega">
                                    <select class="claim" name="gc-claim-voucher" style="width:145px;">
                                        <option value="" <%= !claim.voucher || claim.voucher == "" || claim.voucher == "undefined" ? 'selected="selected"' : '' %> >None</option>
                                        <option value="GC_AMAZON_100" <%= claim.voucher && claim.voucher == "GC_AMAZON_100" ? 'selected="selected"' : '' %> >100</option>
                                        <option value="GC_AMAZON_50" <%= claim.voucher && claim.voucher == "GC_AMAZON_50" ? 'selected="selected"' : '' %> >50</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    <% }) %>
                    <a href="javascript: void 0;" class="send-voucher link">Submit</a>
                    <a class="button small voucher-communication-logs">Voucher Communication Logs</a>
                <% } else { %>
                    <div class="detail-body grid_7 alpha omega">
                            <a href="javascript: void 0;" class="add-claim link">+ Add new claim</a>
                    </div>
                <% } %>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: This does not look like valid Twig syntax(especially; `<% }) %>`, `<% } else { %>`, `<% } %>` look wrong), see: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/if.html. Are you sure you are using Twig and not some other templating engine?

Comment: I am using twig itself.... Can you please help me out over here...

Comment: See basically what I want to do is disable the send voucher button until the voucher amount option is selected...